# Riot League-v4 API returns empty response body with status code 200

Tags: c, json, curl, riot-games-api

I need help with the RIOT API, basically i'm doing a chatbot in C Language, and i need to `curl` the data from RIOT API to get the stats of a summoner.

I've tried the Summoner-v4 API and it worked, now i need to use the summoner id found in the response body of the Summoner-v4 API, to `curl` the data i need from the League-v4 API. But everytime i make a request with the id of a different username from the one registered in the riot dev site, it returns status code 200 (which indicated there was no error in the request) but an empty response body with just `[]`.

What's the problem here? Am i allowed to see the stats of other players?

Answer (score 0):

If the LEAGUE-V4 endpoint return a empty array [] it meen's that the summoner is unrank in solo queue and flex

Basically LEAGUE-V4 returns a array of queues like this :

```json
[
    {
        "leagueId": "blalbla_leagueId",
        "queueType": "RANKED_FLEX_SR",
        "tier": "PLATINUM",
        "rank": "I",
        "summonerId": "blalbla_summonerId",
        "summonerName": "blalbla_summonerName",
        "leaguePoints": 60,
        "wins": 28,
        "losses": 21,
        "veteran": false,
        "inactive": false,
        "freshBlood": false,
        "hotStreak": false
    },
    {
        "leagueId": "blalbla_leagueId",
        "queueType": "RANKED_SOLO_5x5",
        "tier": "DIAMOND",
        "rank": "I",
        "summonerId": "blalbla_summonerId",
        "summonerName": "blalbla_summonerName",
        "leaguePoints": 100,
        "wins": 38,
        "losses": 23,
        "veteran": false,
        "inactive": false,
        "freshBlood": false,
        "hotStreak": false,
        "miniSeries": {
            "target": 3,
            "wins": 2,
            "losses": 1,
            "progress": "WWLNN"
        }
    }
]
```